# DSolveValue and Laplace-Beltrami diffusion equation

Tags: differential-equations

I started using Mathematica very recently and I am considering a 2D diffusion process, involving a Laplace-Beltrami potential term Pot[x,y]. My code is given just below

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Pot[x_, y_] := 1;
heqn = D[u[x, y, t], t] ==  Pot[x, y]*(D[u[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y, t], {y, 2}]);
ic = u[x, y, 0] == E^(-x^2 - y^2);
sol = DSolveValue[{heqn, ic}, u[x, y, t], {x, y, t}]; Plot3D[ Evaluate[Table[sol, {t, 0, 4}]], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotRange -> All, Filling -> Axis]
ListAnimate[Table[Plot3D[sol, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "SolidGrid"}, AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*StyleBox[\"x\", \"SO\"]\) (m)", " \!\(\*
StyleBox[\"y\", \"SO\"]\) (m)", "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"u\", \"SO\"]\) (\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(K\), \(-2\)]\))"}, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> {0, 1.1}], {t, 0, 4, .01}]]
```

This is a copy/paste from a basic 1D program and hence it can only work fine. But when I am changing the potential Pot[x,y] for a non-trivial function of x and y (such as  `Pot[x_,y_]:=(((x+0.5)^2+y^2)^{1/6})*(((x-0.5)^2+y^2)^{1/6})`), Mathematica cannot provide me with any result (only a message pointing out the problem *DSolveValue::nolist: There should be no lists on either side of the equations*). Does anyone know how to fix my mistake please ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Braces (`{...}`] are used for lists, not to group mathematical expressions or as in LaTeX. In your new `Pot`  expression change the braces surrounding the exponents to normal parentheses `(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I changed accordingly ! But Mathematica remains unhappy with my code...

Comment: With `Pot[x_, y_] := (((x + 1/2)^2 + y^2)^(1/6)*(((x - 1/2)^2 + y^2)^(1/6)))` there are no errors generated. But Mathematica can not solve it analytically now. I do not know if this is what you mean by _Mathematica remains unhappy with my code_. If so, you could try numerical solution. That always works :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Nasser. I am trying numerical solutions (by replacing DSolveValue by NDSolve), but this still does not worK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying numerical solutions (by replacing DSolveValue by
> NDSolve), but this still does not worK.

May be you did not do something right. Hard to know since you did not show the code ;)

[image]

I made up some boundary conditions and some arbitrary range. You can change all that ofcourse.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
Pot[x_, y_] := (((x + 1/2)^2 + y^2)^(1/6)*(((x - 1/2)^2 + y^2)^(1/6)))
heqn = D[u[x, y, t], t] == 
   Pot[x, y]*(D[u[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y, t], {y, 2}]);
ic = u[x, y, 0] == E^(-x^2 - y^2);
bc = {u[0, y, t] == 0, u[1, y, t] == 0, u[x, 0, t] == 0, 
   u[x, 1, t] == 1};
sol = NDSolveValue[{heqn, ic, bc}, u, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

And now

```
Animate[Plot3D[sol[x, y, t0], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 1}}], {t0, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: Great, it works now. Thanks very much for your help !